# Keyboard shortcut to access search bar within website? Mac OS X

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, search, safari

Using Safari, but curious if this is applicable for other browsers too.

I use CMD-L to quickly access the address bar, but I'm having trouble finding a shortcut for quickly getting to a search bar within a website?

Answer (score 1):

*CMD-OPTION-F* will take you to the search bar.  See here:
http://christianboyce.blogspot.com.au/2012/01/my-new-favorite-keyboard-shortcut.html

Alternatively *CMD-F* will allow you to search the text on an existing page you have open.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>  
 <sub>Can't think of anything else to say ;)</sub>